# Running and closing a program on a timeline VBS

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a vb script that opens an application and then clicks in set spots to get the app to work and then after 15 minutes kills the program but I don't know how and can't find out how to get it to work.

I have this so far,

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Codin\Codin\Codin.exe"
//Now it doesn't run for some reason, it won't open the program in my downloads?
//right here is where I'd put the script for the clicking on certain areas
//then put the time script above this
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.run "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Codin\Codin.bat\\
//The .bat file is to run
@ECHO OFF
TASKKILL /F /IM Codin.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

Moving the mouse and forcing mouse clicks can create a [hostile user environment](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Control_Systems_Design/Hostile_Environment).

You can try this, however:

```
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dX As Long, ByVal dY As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Process.Start("C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Codin\Codin\Codin.exe")
Dim x As Integer = 150 ' The x position on the screen
Dim y As Integer = 150 ' The y position on the screen
Cursor.Position = New Point(x, y) 
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN Or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0
Application.DoEvents()
Threading.Thread.Sleep(900000) ' Sleep 900,000 milliseconds, or 15 minutes
Process.Start("C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Codin\Codin.bat")
```

You may have to do it in vb.NET, since VBS doesn't support many functions that vb.NET does, and you can wrap it up in an executable.

More on the force mouse click method: https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic/answers/641974-force-mouse-click